# JHipster adding JPA @ManyToMany stops application from booting

Tags: database, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I've been working on a JHipster project for the past few things and things have been going relatively smoothly. There are several relationships in my application's data model and i've iterated my data model several times, adding new entities and updating existing with entities with new relationships with no issue.

For some unknown reason, adding a new @ManyToMany or @OneToMany relationship between two entities seems to stop the application from booting. The application seems to be just about to boot and stops, logging a GC warning every few seconds like:
`[gc][30] overhead, spent [993ms] collecting in the last [1.3s]`

The offending entity looks like:

```
Long id;

@OneToMany //Relationship works fine
Set<OtherClass> otherClassObjects = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany //Working ok. 
@JoinTable(name, joinColumns, inverseJoinColumn)
Set<User> users = new HashSet();

@ManyToMany //Causes application to hang. The user entity is also linked to this entity with two @ManyToMany relationships, both are functional. 
@JoinTable(name, joinColumns, inverseJoinColumn)
Set<Places> Places = new HashSet();
```

I know this may not be enough information to fully diagnose the issue but i'd appreciate any guidance as to how best to troubleshoot this problem. I'm nearly sure it's this relationship that's causing the issue as rolling back the changes needed to create the relationship allow the application to boot as normal.

Comment: Can you run it in debug mode, stop it and step through the code to see what it is doing?

Comment: Is it possible you are running into circular references in your model? Try using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` in your relationship definitions.